# Is there a good way to buy molded LEGO boxes?

Tags: shopping

I'm considering some new storage options, and there are some official LEGO boxes that I'd like to use as they already fit in my existing shelving system. The following sets contain the boxes that I'd like to use:

[image: 10698]

[image: 10676]

[image: 10580]

I wouldn't mind picking up a few copies of the classic brick box for the parts, but I'm less excited about the others. I'd like to get a variety of colors of these boxes, and they aren't widely available on Bricklink.

Is there a good way to get these boxes without buying several copies of each of these sets?

Answer (score 1):

I have considered this as well as the boxes look nice and they are stackable. However after taking into consideration how difficult it was going to be to acquire these boxes in sufficient quantity, be able to expand the system as my collection grows, and the fact that even the largest box is quite small, I decided against it. It is just not worth it.

Also, the boxes are not really practical for storage. They are narrow and deep, meaning it is hard to find pieces. I prefer wider and shallower containers where it is easier to see what's inside. It is best to go with a generic storage system readily available at department stores. They are made to be practical for storage, they are cheap, and can be expanded as your collection grows. If you would like to have the LEGO-ish look, you can always paint your shelves in bright colors, add posters, LEGO stickers, etc.

However if you really-really want these boxes, you might want to team up with eBay or BrickLink sellers who don't really care for the boxes but sell the parts. Try to reach out to larger sellers who buy sets in quantities, so you can get a number of boxes at a time.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm only thinking of using these as part of my storage system. I primarily use 3700 series Plano storage, and these boxes have a similar footprint so they'd fit on my shelves nicely. I was thinking I could use them for awkward large pieces such as battery boxes, BURPs, train track, etc.

Comment: That's a good solution. If you don't have to depend on these boxes and they are just part of your storage system (as you mentioned), then yeah, they can be a nice supplementary option. They are well-made and strong, and they are stackable. Plus they do look very LEGO-ish. In my opinion they are a lot more practical than those awfully designed storage boxes that are made to look like LEGO bricks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that cheap quantities of the duplo box will be hardest to find since virtually all who buy it will be buying it for small children and will probably keep the box to store the bricks. Also, it probably wouldn't occur to anyone that there might be resale value to the box itself. These boxes will likely end up getting played with until they're too beat up to use as nice display boxes, and/or will end up in a recycling bin somewhere.

Depending on how determined you are to get these boxes, I'd see if you couldn't find a toy store that would let you post a notice near the duplo boxes stating that you're willing to buy them, or that would pass your contact info to customers who buy a box. Failing that, I'd buy a pile of the yellow ones and paint them.